# Expressing a point in two coordinate systems

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Let $(O,e_1,e_2,e_3)$ and $(O',e_1',e_2',e_3')$ be two coordinate systems. Let $\overline{OO'}=2e_1-e_2+3e_3$, $e'_1=e_1-e_2+3e_3$, $e'_2=e_1+e_2+e_3$ and $e'_3=e_1-e_2-e_3$.

a) Find the coordinates of a point A in $(O',e_1',e_2',e_3')$ if the coordinates
of A in $(O,e_1,e_2,e_3)$ are $(2,3,4)$.

b) Find the coordinates of a point A in $(O,e_1,e_2,e_3)$ if the coordinates
of A in $(O',e_1',e_2',e_3')$ are $(2,3,4)$.

Where should I use the information about $\overline{OO'}$? Isn't the answer of a) $(11,9, -5)$?

Comment: Sorry, what is $O$? A point? Also, do you know about linear algebra? In particular, do you know what a basis is?

Comment: $O$ is the origin and a basis is a collection of linearly independent vectors that can represent any vector in a given coordinate system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have equations expressing $e_i$'s in terms of $e_i$, you need inverse equations expressing $e_i$ in terms of $e_i$'s, so express your equations as a matrix
$$\left(
\begin{array}{c}
e_1'\\
e_2'\\
e_3'
\end{array}\right)=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 &-1&3\\
1&1&1\\
1&-1&-1
\end{array}
\right)\left(
\begin{array}{c}
e_1\\
e_2\\
e_3
\end{array}
\right)$$
Taking the inverse matrix you get
$$\left(
\begin{array}{c}
e_1\\
e_2\\
e_3
\end{array}\right)=\frac{1}{4}\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
0 &2&2\\
-1&2&-1\\
1&0&-1
\end{array}
\right)\left(
\begin{array}{c}
e_1'\\
e_2'\\
e_3'
\end{array}
\right)$$
which gives you expressions of $e_i$'s in terms of $e_i'$'s.

Now, part a): you have that the coordinates
of A in $(O,e_1,e_2,e_3)$ are $(2,3,4)$, hence
$$A=O+2e_1+3e_2+4e_3$$

$$=O'+\overline{O'O}+2e_1+3e_2+4e_3$$
$$=O'-\overline{OO'}++2e_1+3e_2+4e_3$$
$$=O'-(2e_1-e_2+e_3)+2e_1+3e_2+4e_3$$
$$=O'+4e_2+3e_3$$
Now replace $e_2$ and $e_3$ with their expressions in terms of $e_2'$ and $e_3'$ giving
$$A=O'-\frac{3}{4}e_1'+2e_2'-\frac{5}{4}e_3'$$
so $A$ has coordinates $(-\frac{3}{4},2,-\frac{5}{4})$ in the coordinate system $(O',e_1',e_2',e_3')$.

Similarly for part b).